# Adding a COUNT option to my resque.rake file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, backgroundworker, resque

I have an existing `resque.rake` file that lets me run `heroku rake jobs:work` to spawn a resque worker. Here is the file:

```
require 'resque/tasks'

task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'
end

desc "Alias for resque:work (To run workers on Heroku)"
task "jobs:work" => "resque:work"
```

Now I want to add a specified number of workers by adding the `COUNT=X` option, but I am unsure where and how to add it to my rake file. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would thing you could just add another `ENV[]` key/value:

```
task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'
  ENV['COUNT'] = 5
end
```

Comment: with a space in between the two pairs?

Comment: yup, just add quotes around the `5`

Comment: actually no... it just keeps spawning one additional worker :/